# No errors fopen php but the file is still not being created

Tags: php, file, fopen

```
$abc = @fopen('http://' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '/pss.txt', 'ab');
if(!$abc)
{echo "<br /><br />Zamowienie Panstwa nie moze zostac przyjete w tej chwili. Prosze sprobowac pozniej.";}
$ciagwyjsciowy = $CPU."\t".$Cenazamowienia_netto."\t".$Cenazamowienia_brutto."\n";
fwrite($abc, $ciagwyjsciowy);
fclose($abc);
```

So the problem is I have no errors whatsoever and the site doesn't create the file.

Comment: Get rid of the `@` symbol. It hides your errors.

Comment: It was without @ earlier I just changed it still no errors

Comment: Is the file at the root of the server?  Make sure the path to the file is correct.  If the file is in the same directory as the script, get rid of the slash. Make it just 'pss.txt' instead.

Comment: No live code-examples. Re-create a minimal example from scratch that demonstrates your issue for the use to ask a question.

Answer (score 4):

You can't write through the `http` protocol.

You will have to specify a filesystem path.